# how to show a close button "x" for soft keyboard in LibGdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I use LibGdx for my app development. I was able to put textfield in my stage and when the textfield get focus, the soft keyboard will show at the bottom of screen, but I would like to have the soft keyboard showing as a window and can have a close button "x" at the right top of the window so that user can close the soft keyboard to finish data entry. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: you want to have your own  keyboard or android keyboard?

Comment: I want to still use the keyboard that I've setup in my phone, for example, I installed google keyboard, and setup the google keyboard to be used in my phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one textfield and you want to close the keyboard that is shown when the textfield is marked you could just add a button with a listener that calls

```
textField.next(true);
```

which focuses the next textfield (and if no more textfields in the scene the keyboard will be closed). Maybe a little bit ugly but I found it the simplest solution.

I'm not sure what you mean by

> but I would like to have the soft keyboard showing as a window

Does that really make sense? Wouldn't you always want to show the keyboard that the user already has installed?